pyrx error VSModel instance has no attribute 'receptorFolder'
An attempt was made to use virtual screening to design new drugs. I just went into pyrx, uploaded the ligand pdb and protein pdb, and clicked 'autodock'->'make ligand','make macromolecule'. However, However, both do not work properly and an error message window appears.Below is the error message that appears.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PyRx\lib\site-packages\PyRx\molNavigator.py", line 136, in OnMakeMacromolecule
mol = self.frame.autodockNav.AddMacromolecule(mol)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PyRx\lib\site-packages\PyRx\autodockNavigator.py", line 75, in AddMacromolecule
item = self.autodockTree.macromoleculeTree.treeDict[self.vsModel.receptorFolder]
AttributeError: VSModel instance has no attribute 'receptorFolder'
Please help me... I'm a beginner who doesn't even know Python and this is my first time using pyrx.
So, I went into the files that showed up in the error and looked at the line sentences, but I couldn't see anything different... What should I change to make the error go away?
